# No route error when GETting root_path, but only in some of my tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing

I have a `root_path` defined in `routes.rb` and I call `get root_path` in other tests, but for some reason, in `test/controllers/application_controller_test.rb`, I get this error when calling `get root_path`:

```
ApplicationControllerTest#test_should_get_index_when_not_logged_in:
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"/", :controller=>"application"}
test/controllers/application_controller_test.rb:10:in `block in <class:ApplicationControllerTest>'
```

Here's `routes.rb`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root               'application#index'
  get    'signup' => 'users#new'
  get    'login'  => 'sessions#new'
  post   'login'  => 'sessions#create'
  delete 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'

  resources :users
  resources :account_activations,  only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets,      only: [:edit, :new, :create, :update]
  resources :lessons,              only: [:show, :index] do
    resources :pre_lesson_surveys, shallow: true,
                                   except:  :destroy
  end
end
```

Here's `application_controller.rb`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  include SessionsHelper

  def index
    render 'admin_home_page' if admin?
    render 'user_home_page'  if logged_in?
    @user = User.new         unless logged_in?
  end
end
```

and here's one of the `tests`

```
test "should get index when not logged in" do
  get root_path
  assert_response :success
  assert_not is_logged_in?
  assert_template 'application/index'
end
```

I'm sure I'm just doing something stupid, but I can't put my finger on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make sure that the `index` template gets rendered on a request to your root path, a request spec may be appropriate:

`spec/requests/application_requests_spec.rb`:

```
describe "Test Root Path" do
  it 'successfully renders the index template on GET /' do
    get "/"
    expect(response).to be_successful
    expect(response).to render_template(:index)
  end
end
```

If you want to make sure that the `index` template gets rendered on a request to the index action of your `ApplicationController`, a controller spec may be appropriate.

`spec/controllers/application_controller_spec.rb`:

```
describe ApplicationController do
  describe "GET index" do
    it "successfully renders the index template" do
      expect(controller).to receive(:index)
      get :index
      expect(response).to be_successful
      expect(response).to render_template(:index)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm already working with a testing set-up primarily not written with rspec. Is there a way to do this without rspec? I've tried changing the test to just `get "/"` and it didn't work, if that helps

Comment: That works, any idea why `get root_path` or `get "/"` didn't work but this does?

Comment: awesome :-)
for controller spec you need to use: `get :index` :-)
and for request spec you use `get "/"`
as shown in my above two examples.

Comment: To know more about controller spec (RSpec): https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-13/docs/controller-specs

Comment: @BenMuschol would consider giving an upvote to my answer if that helped?